# Disjoint quora slices and global ledger status.

Tags: stellar

**Theoretically**, if all the nodes in the quorum *participate only in disjoint slices*, then there wouldn't ever be a single global state of the ledger. Does Stellar help identify such scenarios in the network (main or private)?

From the [Stellar Consensus Protocol article](https://medium.com/a-stellar-journey/on-worldwide-consensus-359e9eb3e949#.ypr1n6ps1), there is a universe of nodes of which a quorum of nodes is enough to arrive at a 'final' ledger state.

> To tolerate Byzantine failure, SCP is designed not to require
>   unanimous consent from the complete set of nodes for the system to
>   reach agreement, and to tolerate nodes that lie or send incorrect
>   messages.

Then, there is a quorum slice that is a collection of certain nodes within the quorum mentioned above.

> Federated Byzantine agreement introduces the concept of a quorum
>   slice, the subset of a quorum that can convince one particular node of
>   agreement.

These quorum slices may or may not intersect. [image]

Comment: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1157